# Replace every symbol of the word after delimiter using python re

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, positive-lookbehind

I would like to replace every symbol of a word after `-` with `*`.

For example:

```
asd-wqe ffvrf    =>    asd-*** ffvrf
```

In TS regex it could be done with `(?<=-\w*)\w` and replacement `*`. But default python regex engine requires lookbehinds of fixed width.

Best I can imaging is to use

```
(?:(?<=-)|(?<=-\w)|(?<=-\w{2}))\w
```

and repeat lookbehing some predetermined big number of times, but it seems not very sustainable or elegant.

Is it possible to use default `re` module for such a task with some more elegant pattern?

Demo for testing [here](https://regex101.com/r/JJjuUw/1).

P.S. I'm aware that alternative regex engines, that support lookbehind of variable length exist, but would like to stick with default one for a moment if possible.

Comment: Do you mean a single pattern, not using re.sub with a callback as a second step replacing characters?

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I believe callback will be suitable as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can not do that with Python re, as you want to match a single character knowing that to the left is `-` followed by optional word characters.

I would write it like this with a callback and then get the length of the match for the replacement of the `*` chars

```
import re

strings = [
    "asd-wqe ffvrf",
    "asd-ss sd",
    "a-word",
    "a-verylongword",
    "an-extremelyverylongword"
]
pattern = r"(?<=-)\w+"
for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, lambda x: len(x.group()) * "*", s))
```

Output

```
asd-*** ffvrf
asd-** sd
a-****
a-************
an-*********************
```

See a [python demo](https://ideone.com/MBrua0).

---

An alternative to a quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is using the `\G` anchor (which is also not supported by Python re)

```
 (?:-|\G(?!^))\K\w
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ohemzm/1)

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to python, and wasn't aware of possibility to pass callback to `re.sub()`

Answer (score 1):

You can capture all the word characters after `-` and pass a callback to `re.sub` that replaces the match with a string of asterisks of the same length.

```py
s = 'asd-wqe ffvrf'
res = re.sub(r'(?<=-)\w+', lambda m: '*' * len(m.group()), s)
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcw9EoIwEAbQPqf4ut1FoLFzZLyITRgSZYb8uAkynj5q@4qXP/WZ4rm1NeSkFepMwQSyZRmOl4P3b/Vk1P1V3Vj2mZX4dp0GuR8n6rHZMC8W4QLqCB02FzmMD017ZpEeRUzWNVb@HdLaFw)

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to python, and wasn't aware of possibility to pass callback to `re.sub()`